# SQL Server 2016 - Linked server error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have an issue with connecting to a linked server from SQL Server 2016 to an Ingres 10.1 database via an Ingres 64bit driver ODBC connection setup in ODBC data source admin - odbc connection succeeds and the linked server connection test succeeds.

T-SQL used for testing has been:

```
select *  
from openquery("linked server", 'select * from "table"')
```

Some tables come back fine although most tables retrieve the columns but have no data throwing the error:

> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "" reported an error. Provider caused a server fault in an external process.
>
> Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server

I have tried changing the provider settings to "Allow in process" on/off; both settings still do not work. If I turn the above setting on i get the error:

The provider reported an unexpected catastrophic failure.

> Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Also a stack dump is created within the SQL logs saying EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION.

I have played with the security connection settings of the linked server but no luck.

Any ideas fellow DBAs?

Comment: Your *fellow DBA* hang out on [**http://dba.stackexchange.com**](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - here, we're ***DEVELOPERS*** :-)